# Can't find the error with the following sum involving multiplicative functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, multiplicative-function, euler-product

I apologize for this question which might be trivial but I'm stuck with this issue and I'm probably doing some mistake over and over again. Here's the framework.
Let $f$ and $h$ be two multiplicative functions and, for a fixed positive integer $m$, consider the sum
$$
S_m = \sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)\prod_{p\mid \gcd(m,n)} h(p)\;.
$$
Since $\gcd(m,n)$ is multiplicative as a function of $n$, I define 
$g_m(n)=\prod_{p\mid \gcd(m,n)} h(p)$ when $\gcd(m,n)>1$ and $g_m(n)=1$ otherwise, so we have
$$
S_m = \sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)g_m(n)\;.
$$
But $f(n)g(n)$ is again multiplicative, so we can perform Euler product expansion. In particular, I'm interested in functions of the type
$$
f(n)=\frac{\mu(n)}{f'(n)}\;,
$$
with $f'(n)$ again multiplicative and $\mu(n)$ being the Moebius function. This simplifies Euler product because
$$
\sum_{k\geq 0} f(p^k) = 1+f(p)\;.
$$
Then, 
$$
S_m =\prod_p [1+f(p)g_m(p)] = \prod_{p\nmid m}[1+f(p)]\prod_{p\mid m}[1+f(p)g_m(p)] =S \prod_{p\mid m} \frac{1+f(p)g_m(p)}{1+f(p)}\;,
$$
that is
$$
S_m = C_m S\;,
$$
where 
$$
S:=\prod_p [1+f(p)]=\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)\;.
$$

Now consider the simple following example with $m=2$: on one hand we have 
$$
S_2=\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)g_2(n) = \sum_{\substack{n\geq 1 \\2\nmid n}} f(n) +
h(2)\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1 \\2\mid n}} f(n)\;.
$$
If my computations are correct, I can't understand how the latter expression could become a multiple of $S$? Where's my mistake?

Thanks in advance and happy new year!

Comment: Hint: $f(2k)/f(2)$ is a multiplicative function of $k$. (This nice trick works with any fixed integer in place of $2$.) Therefore the second sum in your last example is a constant times an Euler product, which can be related back to $S$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks Greg! So my computations are correct! That's a big relief! Happy 2016!!!